# Join 3 tables in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, collection, magento2.1.0, join

I am new to magento 2, And want to join 4 tables.

```
TABLE 1) market_p_userdata (columns -> seller_id, image)
TABLE 2) market_product (columns -> seller_id, magepro_id)
TABLE 3) catalog_category_product (columns -> product_id)
TABLE 4) customer_entity (columns-> entity_id)

TABLE 3) product_id (primary key) which is as a foriegn key in TABLE 2) named as magepro_id,

TABLE 4) enity_id(primary key) which is foreign key in TABLE 3) AND 2) named as seller_id,

TABLE 2) seller_id(primary key) which is foreign key in TABLE 1) named as seller_id,
```

I want to get Image of seller and name of seller, I have searched many links, But still I am not getting how to create join.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the simple example how you can join multiple tables in Magento

```
   protected $_productCollectionFactory;  


      public function __construct(

            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory

        ) {


            $this->_productloader = $_productCollectionFactory;

        }

    public getmyCollection(){
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
                ['table1join'=>$collection->getTable('table1join')],
                'e.entity_id = table1join.product_id',
                ['column1'=>'table1join.column1','column2'=>'table1join.column2']);
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
                ['table1join'=>$collection->getTable('table1join')],
                'e.entity_id = table1join.product_id',
                ['table2column1'=>'table1join.column1','table2column1'=>'table1join.column2']);
       $collection->getSelect()->join(
            ['table2join'=>$collection->getTable('table2join')],
            'e.entity_id = table2join.product_id',
            ['table3column1'=>'table2join.column1','table3column1'=>'table2join.column2']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I want to join 4 table not 2 tables,  Kindly answer for 4 tables. I have searched for 2 tables as I have mentioned in question.

Comment: @Khushbu_sipl These are 3 tables first was the collection two are attached with join if  you want to add another join just  add another like  i do for fourth

Comment: okay, I am trying will let you know when its done. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Joining a Table in a collection is so simple in magento2:

```
      $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['secondTable'=>$this->getTable('sales_order_address')],
            'main_table.id = secondTable.entity_id','*');
      $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['thirdTable'=>$this->getTable('sales_order_grid')],
            'main_table.id = thirdTable.entity_id', '*');

      }
```

You can Add numerous Table like this.. Hope it will help All. :)